# 'if x % 2: return True' , wouldn't that return True if the number was divisible by 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't understand how `if not x % 2: return True` works. Wouldn't that mean this if x is not divisible by two, return True? That's what i see in this code.

I see it as `if not x % 2: return True` would return the opposite of if a number is divisible by 2, return True.

I just don't understand how that part of the syntax works.

```
def is_even(x):
    if not x % 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Would `if 0` return True? On a sidenote `return not x % 2` would be a nicer way to write it

Comment: When in doubt, print! `print(x % 2, not x % 2)` would show you how the calculation shakes out.

Answer (score 10):

> Wouldn't that mean this if x is not divisible by two, return True?

No, because when x is not divisible by 2 the result of `x%2` would be a nonzero value, which will be evaluated as `True` by Python, so its `not` would be `False`.

Read more about [Truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in python.

Comment: Thanks @Kasramvd for the answer it really helps with my understanding of what modulo is and how to use it.

Answer (score 7):

The modulo operator `%` returns the remainder of a division. If `x` is divisible by 2 ('even'), then the remainder is zero and `x % 2` thus evaluates to zero (=False), which makes the whole expression True.

Answer (score 1):

note, to add to the other answers: `x % 2` does not mean "x is divisible by 2"; instead, it is the modulo operator, and returns the value `y` such that `x` is congruent to `y` (mod 2), which is really just the remainder of dividing `x` by 2.

Here is a fix for your code:

```
def is_even(x):
    if not x % 2 == 0:
        # if x is divisible by two, the
        # remainder will be 0
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

See also: The modulo operator, in the [python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) (under "Binary Arithmetic Operators", fourth paragraph down.

Comment: even though this is a horrible antipattern ... just `return not x%2`  i really hate `if True: return True`... that said +1 for explaining modulo to him

Answer (score 0):

If the remainder of X / 2 is 0, then return true

```
2 % 2 = 0


!0 = true
```

Answer (score 0):

If operation `X modulo 2 = 0`, function returns true - which means that the number is even.

Operation modulo 2 returns the remainder from division by 2.

**Example:**

`5 % 2 = 1` because `5 = 2*2 + 1`

`7 % 2 = 1` because use `7 = 3*2 + 1`

`6 % 2 = 0` because `6 = 3*2 + 0`

Answer (score 0):

Simpler and readable is for instance

```
def is_even(x): 
    return x % 2 == 0
```

where it explicitly tells the expression must equate zero in order for the function to return `True`.